# Need to add an <li> at the end of each ul on a page

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to add an `<li> </li>` to each UL within a certain div on my page. Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="sfmg-thumbs-wrapper" style="width: 67px;">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#"><img width="20" height="20" alt="Photo Title Here 1" src="images/temp/portfolioImage1.jpg"></a></li> 
<li class=""><a href="#"><img width="20" height="20" alt="Photo Title Here 2" src="images/temp/portfolioImage2.jpg"></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#"><img width="20" height="20" alt="Photo Title Here 3" src="images/temp/portfolioImage3.jpg"></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#"><img width="20" height="20" alt="Photo Title Here 4" src="images/temp/portfolioImage4.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="sfmg-thumbs-wrapper" style="width: 67px;">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#"><img width="20" height="20" alt="Photo Title Here 1" src="images/temp/portfolioImage1.jpg"></a></li> 
<li class=""><a href="#"><img width="20" height="20" alt="Photo Title Here 2" src="images/temp/portfolioImage2.jpg"></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#"><img width="20" height="20" alt="Photo Title Here 3" src="images/temp/portfolioImage3.jpg"></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#"><img width="20" height="20" alt="Photo Title Here 4" src="images/temp/portfolioImage4.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to insert a LI tag to the end of each div. Here is the jquery I was using:

```
$('.sfmg-thumbs-wrapper').each(function() {
$('.sfmg-thumbs-wrapper').find('.sfmg-thumbs-wrapper li:last').appendTo('<li class="info"/>');
});
```

This is not working. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try just this (no each needed)?

```
$('.sfmg-thumbs-wrapper ul').append('<li class="info"/>')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `$('.sfmg-thumbs-wrapper ul').append('<li class="info"/>');`

Comment: Three nearly identical answers... haven't seen that for a long time.

Comment: Nowadays everyone "does" jQuery :)

Comment: I guess making it more complicated is not always necessary!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('.sfmg-thumbs-wrapper ul').append('<li class="info"/>');
```

With `appendTo` it would be vice versa:

```
$('<li class="info"/>').appendTo('.sfmg-thumbs-wrapper ul');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, and I am sure I will be corrected on this, if you wanted your code to work as it was you should have done this:

```
$('.sfmg-thumbs-wrapper').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li:last').appendTo('<li class="info"/>');
});
```

But as other said, thats not a good way to do things.  Try to avoid looping it you can.

Comment: This won't work. It would append the last `li` to `<li class="info"/>` .